# Write line of HTML code with VBA

Tags: html, vba

I have a macro that publishes my sheet as an HTML page, and it works well...however the background margin is the wrong color. I need it to be black. I've found that if I edit the html code once the webpage is published, I can easily fix the problem - all I need to do is add the line below:

```
<body bgcolor="black">
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to have my macro open up the webpage, add the line of html code, and then save and close the file?

The code that publishes the sheet is below:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange,_
       Filename:=SavePath, Sheet:="HTML", Source:="$A1:N" & numProc, HtmlType:=0)
.Publish (True)
.AutoRepublish = False
End With
```

Comment: What code does your macro use currently?  Please post the code which deals with the publishing of the HTML page.  SO is not a code outsourcing platform.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more.

Comment: I added the code above

Answer (score 2):

You could (and should) simply use CSS. Create a `*.css` file in the same folder as where you save your HTML file(s). Then in your HTML `<head>` just add this:

```
<head>
<link href="my-file.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

And in the CSS file:

```
body {
    background-color: #000000; /* or just background-color: black; */
}
```

---

<strike>Then in your body:</strike>

```
<body class="background">
```

And in the CSS file:

```
body.background {
  background-color: #000000; /* or just background-color: black; */
}
```

This will make any file with the HTML attributes have the same background. As far as making VB generate that, probably not the best tool for the job.

Comment: you only ever have one Body tag per page, so there is really no need for a class at all. other than that I agree

Comment: Ok, but I'm trying to automate publishing this sheet, as I will be doing it very frequently.  I want to avoid manually going into every webpage that I publish using this macro and editing the html.  Is there a way to add the reference to the CSS file automatically?

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. That should do exactly what you need with CSS with no need to edit files manually. I feel sure there is a way to add the reference with VBA, perhaps someone else can chip in.